# Why decorator is giving missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, decorator, positional-argument

hey developer I am just exploring decorator so there I got some error  missing 1 required positional argument. but when I driving code in calling function i am providing particular value first look my code.

```
def main(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        r, pi = func()
        return pi * r
    return wrapper


@main
def area(r, pi=3.14):
    return r, pi



#drive
print(area(r=10))
```

Comment: `r, pi = func()` You are missing a value for `r` argument (`pi` has a default value)

Comment: not solve same error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `r` argument value in line 3: `r, pi = func()`:
Pass `*args, **kwargs` in the func.

```
def main(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        r, pi = func(*args, **kwargs) ## here
        return pi * r
    return wrapper


@main
def area(r, pi=3.14):
    return r, pi



#drive
print(area(10))
```

This will fix your issue

output: `31.400000000000002`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the wrapper arguments to `func()`:

```
r, pi = func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Without that, it's calling `area()` with no arguments, when `area()` expects at least one argument.